# PHP Sessions on Windows and Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, session

I've faced this problem maybe a week ago and still unable to figure out what is wrong.

I have 2 machines, one is running Windows, the other is running Debian 8.

So the thing is:

1. On Windows code executes as it should
2. On Linux it is a total mess

The problem is with sessions, i'm unable to make them work on Linux.

How they work:
Client Access Website --> PHP Creates Session --> Write to DB (ID, Key, Data) --> Get DB Session --> Check if it correct --> Update Data --> User leaves/log out --> Delete session

What i have:

1. On Windows it works exactly as i described above
2. On Linux script keep adding values to DB (ID and KEY are identical) and not deleting them after logout

From here i cant use authorization on Linux, but it works perfectly on Windows.

**Here is a Sessions Class:**

```
<?php
```

Class Session
{

```
public static $DBConnection;
private static $SessionCreated = false;
private static $Salt;

public function __construct($Database)
{
    session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'Open'), array($this, 'Close'), array($this, 'Read'), array($this, 'Write'), array($this, 'Destroy'), array($this, 'GarbageCollector'));
    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    Session::$DBConnection = $Database::$Connection;
    $FileLocation = getcwd().DS.'Core'.DS.'Libraries'.DS.'FreedomCore';
    $Files = scandir($FileLocation);
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
        unset($Files[$i]);
    if(!empty($Files))
    {
        Session::$Salt = file_get_contents($FileLocation.DS.$Files[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        $RandomFileName = substr( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ,mt_rand( 0 ,25 ) ,1 ) .substr( md5( time( ) ) ,1 );
        $RandomSalt = Session::GenerateRandomSalt();
        file_put_contents($FileLocation.DS.$RandomFileName, $RandomSalt);
        Session::$Salt = $RandomSalt;
    }
}


public static function UpdateSession($Data)
{
    if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        foreach($Data as $key=>$value)
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

public static function SessionStatus()
{
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

private static function GenerateRandomSalt()
{
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789*+|/-';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $charactersLength; $i++)
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    return $randomString;
}

public static function GenerateCSRFToken()
{
    $InitialString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $PartOne = substr(str_shuffle($InitialString),0,8);
    $PartTwo = substr(str_shuffle($InitialString),0,4);
    $PartThree = substr(str_shuffle($InitialString),0,4);
    $PartFour = substr(str_shuffle($InitialString),0,4);
    $PartFive = substr(str_shuffle($InitialString),0,12);
    $FinalCode = $PartOne.'-'.$PartTwo.'-'.$PartThree.'-'.$PartFour.'-'.$PartFive;
    $_SESSION['generated_csrf'] = $FinalCode;
    return $FinalCode;
}

public static function ValidateCSRFToken($Token)
{
    if(isset($Token) && $Token == $_SESSION['generated_csrf'])
    {
        unset($_SESSION['generated_csrf']);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public static function UnsetKeys($Keys)
{
    foreach($Keys as $Key)
        unset($_SESSION[$Key]);
}

public static function Start($SessionName, $Secure)
{
    $HTTPOnly = true;
    $Session_Hash = 'sha512';

    if(in_array($Session_Hash, hash_algos()))
        ini_set('session.hash_function', $Session_Hash);
    ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 6);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

    $CookieParameters = session_get_cookie_params();

    session_set_cookie_params($CookieParameters["lifetime"], $CookieParameters["path"], $CookieParameters["domain"], $Secure, $HTTPOnly);
    session_name($SessionName);
    session_start();
    //session_regenerate_id(true);

    Session::$SessionCreated = true;
}

static function Open()
{
    if(is_null(Session::$DBConnection))
    {
        die("Unable to establish connection with database for Secure Session!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

static function Close()
{
    Session::$DBConnection = null;
    return true;
}

static function Read($SessionID)
{
    $Statement = Session::$DBConnection->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :sessionid LIMIT 1");
    $Statement->bindParam(':sessionid', $SessionID);
    $Statement->execute();
    $Result = $Statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $Key = Session::GetKey($SessionID);
    $Data = Session::Decrypt($Result['data'], $Key);
    return $Data;
}

static function Write($SessionID, $SessionData)
{
    $Key = Session::GetKey($SessionID);
    $Data = Session::Encrypt($SessionData, $Key);

    $TimeNow = time();

    $Statement = Session::$DBConnection->prepare('REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (:sessionid, :creation_time, :session_data, :session_key)');
    $Statement->bindParam(':sessionid', $SessionID);
    $Statement->bindParam(':creation_time', $TimeNow);
    $Statement->bindParam(':session_data', $Data);
    $Statement->bindParam(':session_key', $Key);
    $Statement->execute();
    return true;
}

static function Destroy($SessionID)
{
    $Statement = Session::$DBConnection->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :sessionid');
    $Statement->bindParam(':sessionid', $SessionID);
    $Statement->execute();
    Session::$SessionCreated = false;
    setcookie("FreedomCoreLanguage", null, time()-3600);
    setcookie("FreedomCore", null, time()-3600);
    return true;
}

private static function GarbageCollector($Max)
{
    $Statement = Session::$DBConnection->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE set_time < :maxtime');
    $OldSessions = time()-$Max;
    $Statement->bindParam(':maxtime', $OldSessions);
    $Statement->execute();
    return true;
}

private static function GetKey($SessionID)
{
    $Statement = Session::$DBConnection->prepare('SELECT session_key FROM sessions WHERE id = :sessionid LIMIT 1');
    $Statement->bindParam(':sessionid', $SessionID);
    $Statement->execute();
    $Result = $Statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($Result['session_key'] != '')
        return $Result['session_key'];
    else
        return hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
}

private static function Encrypt($SessionData, $SessionKey)
{
    $Salt = Session::$Salt;
    $SessionKey = substr(hash('sha256', $Salt.$SessionKey.$Salt), 0, 32);
    $Get_IV_Size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $IV = mcrypt_create_iv($Get_IV_Size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $Encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $SessionKey, $SessionData, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $IV));
    return $Encrypted;
}

private static function Decrypt($SessionData, $SessionKey)
{
    $Salt = Session::$Salt;
    $SessionKey = substr(hash('sha256', $Salt.$SessionKey.$Salt), 0, 32);
    $Get_IV_Size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $IV = mcrypt_create_iv($Get_IV_Size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $Decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $SessionKey, base64_decode($SessionData), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $IV);
    return $Decrypted;
}
}

?>
```

**Here is how session initialized:**

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        $Session = new Session($Database);
        $InstallationIsInProgress = false;
        if(isset($_COOKIE['FreedomCore']))
            Session::Start('FreedomCore', false);
    }
```

[Folder with scripts](https://github.com/darki73/FreedomCore/tree/master/Core/Libraries/FreedomCore/System) on github
Important files are **Database.FreedomCore.php** and **Sessions.FreedomCore.php**

**The main question is:**
Why exactly the same code works perfectly on Windows, and cant to work at all on Linux?

*P.S. Servers running exactly the same versions of Apache and PHP*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Stupid question, but did you think about case sensitivity in your database? Windows and Linux machines may handle them differently... As in, Windows is quite case insensitive in most cases while Linux is case sensitive...

Comment: @Raphioly-San that was the first thing i've checked, and nope, everything is in the same case on both sides (web and db). That what confuses me even more, i've even copied entire db, simulated the session but Linux still adds a new value like it is a new session

Comment: Off-topic question: Why are you using `static function` while using `$this` as scope? I think you're confusing `static` for `public`.

Comment: You may want to take another look at [the PHP documentation about session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Comment: @Raphioly-San not at all, some of them is used later as static reference, not to call session constructor in each file

Comment: If the whole purpose of your strategy is to have your own Session handler, then you may not even want to use session register. You don't actually need it. It's recommendable, but not needed...  But if you want to substitute your implementation for the regular session handler functionality, you should not access your class at all and stick to the regular session global and functions... The only thing you should be doing is override default behavior by desired behavior...